# Add border to doughnut chart with Chartist.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts, chartist.js

I'm using Chartist.js in order to create a few doughnut charts. So far it's been pretty straightforward and easy to use, but I've been trying to create a border around the shapes for the last three hours (needless to say I'm unable to use the SVG stroke property since the plugin itself uses the stroke to create the donut effect).

Is there an in-plugin option to give the chart a border?

The way I'm creating the doughnut is really simple:

```
new Chartist.Pie('.donut-chart', {
  series: [37.47, 62.53],
}, {
  donut: true,
  donutWidth: 8,
  startAngle: 0,
  total: 100,
  showLabel: false
});
```

Of course any kind of help will be much appreciated!

EDIT: I've also tried using cdcarson's fork of the plugin (Pull request pending at https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/pull/330) to generate the chart using filled shapes instead of strokes, but something seems to be broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it using a pie chart instead of a doughnut one, and adding strokes to the shapes. After that I created a function to append a cover for the fill:

```
function hideFillOfPie() {
  $('.donut-chart').append('<div class="cover-fill"></div>');
  var size = $('.donut-chart-holder').width();
  $('.cover-fill').css({
    'height' : size - 30 + 'px',
    'width'  : size - 30 + 'px'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  hideFillOfPie();
});
```

The parent of the chart must have set

```
position: relative;
```

And the CSS for the cover of the fill looks like this:

```
.cover-fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  z-index: 1;
}
```